# AWS-Ubuntu-Git Setup error fatal: $HOME not set

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I have some **cloudinit** scripts to execute when my **AWS EC2 Ubuntu** instance starts up.

I want to setup **GIT** config variables, with the code below.

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
- [ sh, -c, "git config --global user.name 'myname'"]
```

When logged into the terminal. I can execute ***git config --global user.name 'myname'*** with no problem.

However when I attempt to start my instance with the **cloudinit** code. I get an error message

> fatal: $HOME not set

My understanding is this is because the **HOME** is not set when the instance starts up.

Looking for a solution, to get the git variable to be set on startup or an alternate solution.

Comment: maybe your script requires a user session

Answer (score 32):

I ran into the same problem...

```
git config --system http.sslVerify false
git config --system user.email "email@email.com"
```

This resolved the error message. I got this solution after reading [CodeCommit with EC2 Role Credentials](https://jameswing.net/aws/codecommit-with-ec2-role-credentials.html). The reason is stated in the blog...
"But when I ran this as root, I ran into the error fatal: $HOME not set, because git config --global is trying to read/write the current user's $HOME/.gitconfig file, and root seems to be $HOME-less in this context.

After being thoroughly schooled in git settings management, I can tell you that there is another option -- to set the system-wide git preferences with git config --system, which results in modifications to /etc/gitconfig, no errors.
"

P.S. I realize that I'm answering this question almost 3 years later, but I'm hoping that this might help others who face the same issue.

Comment: I confirm, setting that context resolve above issue. Thanks!

Comment: confirmed, changing to `git config --system ____` from `git config --global ____` in my user-data script fixed my problem

Comment: Using the sslVerify configuration, I got `error: could not lock config file /opt/etc/gitconfig: Read-only file system` error

Answer (score 3):

I just used sudo and it resolved my problem

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

```
sudo git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
sudo git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm running in an AWS Lambda function and using GitPython and the git CLI.  I found that after the clone command, and before pushing changes, etc. I just needed to set the values locally like this within the directory my code exist:

```
os.system(f'cd {local_repo_path} && git config user.name "project user"')
os.system(f'cd {local_repo_path} && git config user.email "example@example.com"')
```

So basically, I omitted the `--global` or `--system` as my AWS Lambda code could not write to those folders. :)
Hope this helps.